# AngularJS 1.6 -Accessing elements in the component's template

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How can I access an element in my component template from my js code?
Suppose I have many components with this template:

```
<div style="width: inherit; height: inherit;">
    <img class="elem"> </img>
</div>
```

and I want each component's controller to access its own `img` - how can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can inject `$element` into your component controller:

```
componetnController($element) {
    let img = $element.find('img');
}
```